# Is there any way to remove starting time and ending time in NeatAndCleanCalendarEvent, also how to customize the events in it?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Is there any way to customize it a bit further.
Also, how can I remove the start and end time? Link for [NeatAndCleanCalendar](https://morioh.com/p/43e90cddd7ad) example.**

```
class NeatCleanCalendarEvent {
  String summary;
  String description;
  String location;
  DateTime startTime;
  DateTime endTime;
  Color color;
  bool isAllDay;
  bool isDone;

  NeatCleanCalendarEvent(this.summary,
      {this.description = '',
      this.location = '',
      this.startTime,
      this.endTime,
      this.color = Colors.blue,
      this.isAllDay = false,
      this.isDone = false});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to customize it a bit further

Looking at its constructors unfortunately no.
What you can do is fork the project and add whatever fields you need. If you are not experienced leave the default fields as they are needed by the package.

eg

```
class NeatCleanCalendarEvent {
  String summary;
  String description;
  String location;
  DateTime startTime;
  DateTime endTime;
  Color color;
  bool isAllDay;
  bool isDone;
// our new data class to make it dynamic you could use a map
  MyDataModel? mydataModel;

  NeatCleanCalendarEvent(this.summary,
      {this.description = '',
      this.location = '',
      this.startTime,
      this.endTime,
      this.mydataModel,
      this.color = Colors.blue,
      this.isAllDay = false,
      this.isDone = false});
}
```

> Also, how can I remove the start and end time?

You can make `isAllDay=true` , should solve this.

Comment: isAllDay not working

Comment: not following?.